# Como fazer um loop, capturando as chaves e os valores de um objeto

Tags: javascript, loop

Gostaria de fazer um loop em um objeto afim de conseguir capturar a chave e o valor correspondente.

Por exemplo:

```js
const obj = {
  'Chave 1': 'Valor 1',
  'Chave 2': 'Valor 2',
  'Chave N': 'Valor N'
};
```

Gostaria de retornar algo assim:

```
Chave 1 => Valor 1
Chave 2 => Valor 2
Chave N => Valor N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir as duas chave e valor pode fazer assim

```js
var obj = {
  'Name' : 'String 1',
  'Age' : 'String 2',
  'Key N': 'String N'
  }
  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item +' => '+ obj[item]);
    })
```

Comment: Na verdade eu quero retornar a chave também. A sua resposta só faz com que o valor correspondente à chave `Name` seja retornado. Quero retornar o valor e a chave.

Comment: @lffg Tinha entendido de outra forma, fiz  a correção, espero, se era isso que precisa.

Comment: Obrigado, é isso mesmo.